# error: error in setup script: command 'py2exe' has no such option 'exeoptimize'

Tags: python, py2exe

i am trying to build wikidpad src code from http://wikidpad.sourceforge.net/ . but i am getting following error as

> python.exe setup.py py2exe
>   running py2exe
>   error: error in setup script: command 'py2exe' has no such option 'exeoptimize'

Note:
i have installed py2exe using bellow link. following command

> pip install http://sourceforge.net/projects/py2exe/files/latest/download?source=files

Answer (score 0):

this issue is basically because of the customized version in py2exe. so we may have to use that customized version for this deployment